How to Investigate/Repair this Ceiling Leak in the Kitchen
We’ve moved into our townhome 7 years ago and upon home inspection, I was told that there’s an abnormal amount of moisture detected under the shower floor (2nd floor room). The previous owner assured me that there was nothing wrong with it and that it had the barrier and overall proper installation. After 5-6 years we’ve noticed a stain forming on the ceiling of the kitchen.I’ve measured its position and the stain matches location of the shower drain. I’ve assumed that it was due to the Amazon drain catcher that my wife installed as it was oversized and wasn’t covering the grout around the drain. Now today I touched the crumbled paint and realized that the drywall is soaked and it’s soft. See images below. I suspect that there’s standing water there and likely mold forming.
My plan is to make a 4x4” hole around that stain, and use a endoscope camera to investigate. Ideally, I am trying to avoid rebuilding the shower and have a solid fix for the leak, then take down cabinets and rip out bad drywall and redo portion of the box and the ceiling.
Looking for an advice on how to approach this. I do have some basic tools and I have experience with fixing drywall, mudding etc.




remove the old caulk, apply new, let the drywall dry

Your question isn't clear. Do you doubt some aspect of your plan? You know you have drywall to repair at a minimum, so I'd already have cabinets out so they don't also get damaged, and I'd be opening drywall until I'm past the mushy area. Then you see what you see. Come back with more details and a specific question.

tear it out until you find al the wet stuff, replace the source of the leak.  I hope you learned a lesson on "no it's fine" by a seller.

Water leaks can travel, so it might be the drain or it might come from the edge/wall/pipes.
